what does モサ公 mean?
I saw that the suffix 公 used to be used in a positive way, but now in a negative way, if I use someone's name and use 公, then it means I'm making fun of that person? When is it better to use this suffix?
I heard that モサ has a similar fate, that it used to be used in a positive way, but now it's not, but I don't quite understand what it means, I've seen examples where children use it to make fun of their peers. What does モサ mean now and when is it used? And in combination, what will this word and the suffix roughly mean/describe the person to whom this word is applied?

See also https://ja.hinative.com/questions/26480717

The short answer is there is no such word as もさ公 in modern Japanese.
If you look up a slang/argot dictionary, you can find the entry for もさ公 with the definition "泥棒; スリ". However, I didn't know such a word, and neither BCCWJ nor 青空文庫 has even a single instance of it. This means the word もさ公/モサ公 has been virtually nonexistent for the last 150 years or so. Of course, modern Japanese children certainly don't know it. If you heard it from a child in a period drama or a yakuza film set more than 70 years ago, it might mean "thief; pickpocket" as mentioned above, but I don't know its subtle nuances at all. If you think you heard it from a modern child, it would definitely be a mishearing of something else. Or it could have been used simply as a proper noun Mosakō (there seems to be a character by that name in One Piece).
公 is indeed used as a derogatory suffix in words like ポリ公, ワン公 and 先公, but even these have become fairly dated, used almost exclusively by a few crude speakers over 50 years old. I would be fairly surprised if modern children used any of them.
もさ also means 猛者 (brave warrior/strong person), but this isn't a negative word, and I have never heard it used in combination with 公.

yes, this name is from One Piece, I came across different designations of the word モサ and separately the suffix 公 and wanted to know more about what it means, since I saw that the term モサ also conveys the feeling of a hairy, clumsy and uncouth person, in principle, I always received slightly different definitions of this word, so I got confused. If we take One Piece itself, then in English this character was called Shaggy, I also thought that this choice of name is associated with the designation of the word モサ

@Dovolnoeface Then, rather than asking for the meaning of a word as an ordinary noun, you should've asked like "What's the impression of the person name モサ公 in One Piece?" 公 was popular suffix in nicknames and pet names 50-100 years ago, and people would usually feel it's an old male person's nickname. For the モサ part, Some people might wonder if it's related to hairiness, while others might not make such deeper associations. At least, the connection to hairiness is not strong enough to be conclusive.
